# search and replace for pattern with wild cards

Tags: vim, replace, vi

The line I am tyring to search and replace is this -

`(assert (if (>= xAltB_0 yAltA_0) (= after_A0_B0 true) (= after_A0_B0 false)))`

Now I want to replace all the occurences of `B_0` by `C_0` and `B0` by `C0`.

Can I use wild-card logic of vim search and replace to do this thing?

I used this command `:s/B[_]0/B\10/g` but it is not really working.

Can someone help please? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[_]` means one of `_` i.e. precisely `_`

If you mean either _ or nothing say 0 or 1 of `_` like this: `_\?`

Don't forget to put it in a group using `\(` and `\)` to use it with `\1`

i.e.

```
:%s/B\(_\?\)0/C\10/g
```